# underline in OpenXml::Docx using Ruby

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, openxml, docx

I am using the OpenXml::Docx for creating docx and adding some text with some style like double underline, strike. The documentations explains through an example

```
 require "openxml/docx"

 text = OpenXml::Docx::Elements::Text.new("Some text that I want to 
 include in my new OOXML document")
 run = OpenXml::Docx::Elements::Run.new
 run.bold = true
 run << text
 paragraph = OpenXml::Docx::Elements::Paragraph.new
 paragraph << run


document = OpenXml::Docx::Package.new
document.document << paragraph
document.save("/path/where/i/save/things/test.docx")
```

So, I tried to make the text underlined but I was not able to do::

```
run = OpenXml::Docx::Elements::Run.new
run.underline = True
```

The underline tag is present as as property [link](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/openxml-docx/0.10.0/OpenXml/Docx/Properties) but it is not showing in the output docx.
Please let me know the correct method. Also, let me know way to do double underline.

Comment: Can you please provide a **complete, verifiable** example of your current code? I just went through the effort of reproducing your example above and found: `NoMethodError: undefined method 'underline=' for #<OpenXml::Docx::Elements::Run:0x007fec344aa1a0 @children=[]>`

Comment: I got it working..thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the code for the [Underline class](https://github.com/openxml/openxml-docx/blob/master/lib/openxml/docx/properties/underline.rb) for the attributes that can be set.

e.g. You can set the type of underline with this:

```
run = OpenXml::Docx::Elements::Run.new
run.underline.type = :dash
```